# How can we commit assets to a rollup?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

so what I’m wondering, is how can we commit assets to a rollup? Specifically FA2 NTFs. And how can we manage some properties on them via the rollup that will reflect on L1 when the rollups syncs…? Would all this be handle by the kernel?

Question from Asbjorn on Slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transfer FA2 tokens to the rollup either:

- having a dedicated contract which takes ownership of the token and sends a message to the rollup to say so. The contract address will need to be hardcoded in the kernel, to be able to trust the message, when it recieves it (in order to treat it as a deposit of that asset).
- having a 'ticket-token' bridge that again stores the tokens in a contract, and sends tickets on to the rollup. This has the advantage that the bridge contract address does not need to be hardcoded in the kernel, since the kernel has been given additional guarantees about ownership through the use of the ticket type.

The kernel can send outbox messages back to L1, which can be executed once the commitment has been cemented after ~2 weeks. These could, for example, be messages to the holder contract/bridge contract to release the tokens back (to their potentially new owners) on L1.